# Why is this image not staying in place when using the UV Project modifier?

Tags: uv, modifiers

So I am trying to use the UV project modifier to make a uv map stay, even when the mesh is modified. Example:
[image]

[image]

As you can tell, the map stays. The problem is, its not perfect. Part of the pixel in the first image is outside the vertices.
 I used the modifier and an empty to control it,
[image]
 manual rotating, moving, and scaling the empty as needed. When I don't do that, the map looks like this:
[image]
When it should look like this:
[image]
How can I make the uv map stay like in the first 2 pictures without messing up the UV map?

Comment: Have you tried to use one empty per face (create an "arrow" empty, to know how it is pointing)? Each of them pointing its -Z (minus Z) to the corresponding character's face. Add these empties as "projectors" in the modifier. If it does not work, you may upload your file **with** textures packed in it. The link for uploading: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I actually only need it for the face, and the arrows don't help with trying to align it properly. Take a look[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2951" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2951/)

Comment: The **minus** Z axis needs to point to the face (Z axis of the empty at the opposite of your model). Once done, you'll have to move the empty to find the good position and to scale it to adjust the texture size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a setting with 3 empties as projectors on a cube.

- Face: pointing to the cube's face. Z of the empty is opposite to the face
- Right: pointing to the cube's right par. Z of the empty is going right (opposite again)
- Left: same principle

Use "override image" option in the modifier.

Each empty has been moved and scaled to fit the image texture at the wanted location.

**edit** as unclear. If you don't use override option, just make so the empty are well oriented (minus Z pointing to the wanted face). It supposes that you have placed the UV map correctly before using the modifier.

[image]

[image]

[**Related documentation**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/modify/uv_project.html)