# Picture projection on an object

Tags: python, mesh, camera, texture-baking

I have a real picture containing an object.
I have the same object as a mesh but with no texture.
On the picture:
I know the coordinate of the camera, and a few points matching some vertex of the mesh.
Is it possible in blender (python?) to recreate the real world (position the mesh object/Camera in the same position as in the picture) and then project the picture to recreate the texture of the object?

Equivalent to Cinema 4D: Texture->frontal then bake texture on object.

Thank you.

Comment: Once you match the camera placement you can use the [**UV Project Modifier**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/modify/uv_project.html) and set the camera as projector.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57420/confused-about-unwrap-vs-modifier-unwrap/

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76774/projecting-multiple-images-onto-an-object-with-uv-project-modifiers

Comment: Regarding "Once you match the camera placement..." apparently 'Blam' is a good plugin for that and can save a lot of time. https://github.com/stuffmatic/blam