# CCTV in Blender

Tags: camera

Does Blender Have the Lightwave type of CCTV cameras ? I would like to have say 4 characters each with thier own camera pointed at them so when scene is rendering out there will be 4 billboard type of screens that would show all 4 cameras on all 4 screens in background of real time animation. If that explains it. Like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Q2wFjitpZ0

Comment: Just a projection right? Have a look into the UV project modifier: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/modify/uv_project.html Somewhat related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/76774/31447 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/121210/31447

Comment: looked at ALL projection mapping vids and written info, not that.They take already done pics and projects. CCTV takes live camera footage in the scene that is being rendered from all other secondary cameras and uses that to put on the screens. It can be video, and is rendered at same time main scene camera is rendering for output. You can have 10 or more cameras or just 1, say, circling around an object or character and THAT live footage is projected on screen while Main camera is rendering.  Probably not splaining well.

Comment: Please add that to your question @SteveAnderson AFAIK there is no built-in way to "stream" live camera data into the viewport. If so you'd have to use python getting the realtime data transfered over using sockets or something. However, Blender is a content creation tool and I'm not sure whether it would be the right tool for that anyway, since there are dedicated tools to handle realtime data like Unreal or Unity...?

Comment: That's what I am finding.Would have liked to move to blender but CCTV is so needed in projects that I'm going to have to stay with LW because of it. Woulda liked to do dynamics in blender, as they seem to calculate faster. Oh Well. Thanks for the help anyways.